# Changing SQL Datasource stored procedure on button press

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sqldatasource

I have two different stored procedures i'd like to run. The first one as listed will run on start up and display all entries in a database. The 2nd one i want to only run on a button press, which shows only specific entries. Running them both like this may not be the best idea, but I've tried a few different things and no luck so far. Any advice?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDevRequestHistory" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TrackIt %>"
    SelectCommand="DevRequestHistory_SEL2" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDevReqestHistory" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TrackIt %>"
    SelectCommand="DevRequestHistory_SEL" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" />



public void btnShowAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrackIt"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("DevRequestHistory_SEL", connection)) 
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What i ended up doing, was replicating my datagrid in a multiview set up in asp.net. Using that i was able to call different stored procedures into the different datagrids.